# Turn Off httpd service on MySQL Server? (AWS)

Tags: mysql, php, amazon-web-services

I started with one server running Apache, PHP, MySQL. Now I have split off my web server so I am running all the PHP files on one server and my MySQL is still on the original server. Are there services / programs that I can turn off or uninstall from the MySQL Server now, or do I need to keep httpd (etc) running? I know how to turn it off, I need to know if it is okay to turn it off without breaking anything.

I am using Amazon AWS and connecting from the PHP server to the MySQL database using the MySQL Database's Internal DNS / IP Address.

I am using Amazon Linux AMI release 2012.09

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Comment: What linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following commands will work on your distribution.

```
service httpd stop
```

This command will stop the current httpd service. But keep in mind that it is still configured to start up on system boot.

If you would like to configure httpd to no longer start on boot.

```
chkconfig httpd off
```

Answer (score 0):

Httpd is only used if you are planning to serve any content or site. If not, you can shutdown Apache service safely and it won't break anything.

Amazon itself doesn't use Apache in any tasks.